# How to load a transparent div after the page load

Tags: jquery, css

HI I have made a transparent div to show main text of home page brighter in compare to other text of home page of my website.Code for div

```
#transparentdiv {
position:absolute;
top:228px;
width:852px;
height:160px;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.3);
border-radius:8px;
   }
```

I am using this div in home page :

```
 <div id="transparentdiv">

                 <h1><?php echo Configure::read('SearchBarHeading');?></h1>
        <h2><?php echo Configure::read('SearchBarSubheading');?></h2>
        </div>
```

But problem in this at the time  of page loading the transparent div is loading first which not looks good.So I just want to make this transparent div load at the last after other content load of page.

Answer (score 3):

Add `display:none` to this div.

```
#transparentdiv{
    display: none;
    /* other styles */
}
```

and then using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('#transparentdiv').show();
});
```

Comment: or you can create it dynamically after the page load!

Comment: @AminJafari the div content must come from backend(php).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to hide the div initially like :

```
<div id="transparentdiv" style="display:none;"> ....
```

And then on the page load, change that css to "display:block" using javascript / jquery.

eg.

```
$(document.ready(function(){
    $("#transparentdiv").css("display","block");
});
```

Thanks,
Ronak

Comment: Thanks for reply I used your method but its just disable the whole div from screen  even the content inside it, AS I said I have two headings on home page which I want to show bright so when whole page load after that transparent div might load to make these heading bright

Comment: Added new answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can try hiding the div first, then show it with timeout. (500 stands for 0.5 seconds)

```
$("#transparentdiv").hide();

setTimeout(function() {
   $("#transparentdiv").fadeIn();
}, 500);
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to add full details in the comment. So posting this as a new answer:

Ok. Then you can use two different css for 2 different state. In the first css lets say with class "less", change the background opacity and font-color to be very light as if they are transparent. In the second css, lets say with class "more", change that transparency to normal.

Apply "less" class by default to your div.

```
    #transparentdiv.less {
    position:absolute;
    width:852px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    border-radius:8px;
     color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);   
    } 

    #transparentdiv.more 
{
    position:absolute;
    width:852px;    
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    border-radius:8px;
       }
```

and then use jquery to add "more" class on load. Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZMw3/2/)